# Pop-up slider knob value on mouse pointer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[image: energy save system preferences's slider]

I have a slider in my app's preferences.  I'd like to make this slider to display it's knob's value when mouse pointer is on the slider's knob.  (Like the picture which I uploaded, energy save system preferences's slider)

I searched web and found that linking slider with text field (takefloatValue) makes slider's value to visible.  But the text field sticks on preferences window.

How can I make my slider to like energy save system preferences's slider?

Comment: What you could do is set the slider to generate continuous updates, and then wire it up to an action that would pop up a tooltip (or rather, faking a tooltip) using this method: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2003/May/msg00630.html

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement these, and you are done:

1.Set its initial value in `awakeFromNib` method.

2.Each time you scroll, update the tooltip value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer.  Your answer is almost of my aim.  But I'd like to know a bit more.  In your sample code, you use setToolTip in a IBAction.  This means that I need to click button to show tooltip on a slider.  Is there any way to show tooltip without button click, and just move the mouse pointer is moved into the slider portion?  If I need to open new question, I will provide.

Comment: There is no extra button. The 'scroll:' is the action of sliding the scroll view.

Comment: Sorry!!  Since I am a beginner of Objective-C, I don't know that NSSlider can have IBAction.  I only know Button can have IBAction.  Sorry for my poor understanding...

Comment: Its ok. So u learn that almost every ui control are able to send some action. In other words if any object implements nsresponder or subclassed from it. U can put action.

Comment: And do upvote for helping contents and down vote for misleading one. That helps you and other.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It seems that my comment can't be down vote. So I delete one comment.  Do I have to delete my comment all?

Comment: No need. Comments cant be voted up or fown. No points are gained from comments. Infact I asked u to upvote my answer

Comment: Marked your answer is useful.

Comment: How Can I make as the same slider in Cocoa app?